# Conditional coloring in mdframed in latex

Tags: latex

I have a question on conditional coloring of a mdframed. The code below does not work but I cannot figure out why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\colorMap}[1]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{a}{green}{b}{yellow}{c}{red}}[nada]}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed 
[backgroundcolor=\colorMap{a}]
\textbf{Color}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tests from the `xstring` package, you can use a simple `\if ... \fi` and thus avoid problems with expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\def\astring{a}
\def\bstring{b}
\def\cstring{c}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\colorMap}[1]{%
  \if\astring#1
    green%
  \else
    \if\bstring#1
      yellow%
    \else
      \if\cstring#1
        red%
      \else
        white%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=\colorMap{a}]
\textbf{Color}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what your actual use case is, but instead of trying to map colours, maybe it would be easier to just create colours with suitable names?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{good}{green}
\colorlet{medium}{yellow}
\colorlet{bad}{red}

\newenvironment{assessment}[1]{
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=#1]
  \textbf{This assessment is marked as #1}\par
}{
  \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{assessment}{good}
some text
\end{assessment}

\begin{assessment}{medium}
some text
\end{assessment}

\begin{assessment}{bad}
some text
\end{assessment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. The use case is as follows: it is a report template with an overall assessment and an assessment for each section. Let's say 3 grades; good, medium and bad. Each assessment grade is then assigned a color. So I want the color to be automatically assigned based on the grade. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @marcus Define colours with the names `good`, `medium` and `bad` and use these.

Comment: Thx again  for your time, the reason i didn't do that is that I need both the grade and the color. So good is assigned to 'Assessment is good' and then I also need the color.

Comment: @marcus ... and the problem is what? You can use word for many things, not just the colour